# Vote counts can't fit the minus sign

Tags: bug, user-interface, score

The vote counts seem to have enough room to accomodate 3 digits and a negative sign:

[image: -234]

However when the score is expanded to show +/- vote counts...

[image: +130/-364]

The minus sign gets cropped off somehow.

Comment: lol that's 100% the new code license post, right?